# Jenkins location of .bat file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When I run Windows batch command on Windows 7 the bat file is placed in `C:\Windows\Temp`. I tried setting TEMP and TMP variables using ENVInject plugin and also tried setting path in windows batch command. But this does not change the location of .bat file. I want the location to be `C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp  but it is C:\Windows\Temp`.

Please suggest.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. When you run a batch command, batch files are not "placed" in Temp or any other location. They are executed from where they are. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: It kinda makes sense, its just badly worded. I think he means when he runs a batch command in using the built in "Execute Windows batch command" .. when you just type in a batch command via the ui, Jenkins creates a temp file like : `'C:\Users\APPJEN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson2255518196876790510.bat'` .. not sure why yours is going to windows temp tho

Answer (score 1):

You have to start jenkins using this command line argument:

`-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp`

http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Change-java-io-tmpdir-on-master-node-version-1-482-td4643854.html